# Copy the column and paste it with special character

Tags: regex, linux, perl, bash, parsing

I have a input file like

```
C3905550 oder CDS 68 646 . - . asmbl_487
C3905550 oder exon 68 646 . - . asmbl_418
C3918365 oder CDS 42 252 . + . asmbl_445
C3918365 oder exon 42 252 . + . asmbl_443
```

all columns are separed by TAB

I want to create a new output file like :

```
C3905550 oder CDS 68 646 . - . asmbl_487 "asmbl_487"
C3905550 oder exon 68 646 . - . asmbl_418 "asmbl_418"
C3918365 oder CDS 42 252 . + . asmbl_445 "asmbl_445"
C3918365 oder exon 42 252 . + . asmbl_443 "asmbl_443"
```

in the output file last column should be copied and pasted with "" and this new column should be separated by space not by TAB, and rest of column should be like in input file and separated by TAB

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

would this line work for you?

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $0" \""$NF"\""}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
perl -pe 's/\t(\S+)\K$/\t"$1"/m'
```

Comment: Will fail if the last field contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]\+\)$/& "\1"/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\t\([^\t]*\)$/& "\1"/' file
```